# Math font in theorem header is not my custom font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontspec, theorems, unicode-math

I use XeLaTeX, fontspec and unicode-math. When I put some math in the header of a theorem, it is typeset in the default Latin Modern font, instead of the custom font set up with `\setmathfont`.

See the following MWE :

```
%!TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\RequirePackage[hyperref,amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremheaderfont{\sffamily\scshape\bfseries}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\newcommand{\Set}{\mathbf{Set}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[monomorphisms in $\Set$]
Some text involving $\Set$.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: output of the MWE]

Instead of this, I would like one the two following behaviours in the header of the example:

1. `\Set` is typeset using my math font, Libertinus Math, as it is in the body of the example.
2. `\Set` is typeset using my sans serif font, so that it fits into the header of the theorem.

Has anybody an idea of how to solve this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `\setmathfontface{\mathbf}{Libertinus Sans Bold}` or `\setmathfontface{\mathbf}{Linux Libertine O Bold}` (whichever you prefer) to set the `\mathbf` font?

Comment: It works, thanks a lot (with the `Semibold` series instead of `Bold` to mimic the default behaviour)!  But I wonder what is the reason why this is not what is done by default by unicode-math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use `\symbf` (a macro provided by the `unicode-math` package) instead of `\mathbf`.

For the following screenshot, we have `\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}`. And, because no text font is loaded explicitly, `\mathbf` employs the default bold Latin Modern glyphs, *not* the Libertinus Math glyphs. In contrast, `\symbf` does use the bold Libertinus Math glyphs.

[image]

```
%!TeX program = lualatex  %% or xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}
$\mathbf{Set}$ $\symbf{Set}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's perfect so! And you also answered to my answer to @frabjous' comment, thanks. :-D

Comment: @sparusaurata - You're most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times, such problems are due to `ntheorem`; this is one case. Use `amsthm`.

```
%!TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\newtheoremstyle{sfbreak}
  {\topsep}     % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}     % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont} % BODYFONT
  {0pt}         % INDENT
  {\sffamily\scshape\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}           % HEADPUNCT
  {\newline}    % AFTER HEAD SPACE
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % HEAD SPEC
\theoremstyle{sfbreak}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\newcommand{\Set}{\mathbf{Set}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[monomorphisms in $\Set$]
Some text involving $\Set$.
\end{example}

$\mathbf{Eff}\neq\symbf{Eff}$

\end{document}
```

Note that for your usage `\mathbf` is preferable to `\symbf` as the example shows: you *do* want the ligature.

[image]